# Using aside which float right and cover whole page using only css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a page like this [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiOEY.png). Currently I'm working on this sidebar, and since I need to use HTML5 I thought that aside element is a good option. But I have trouble positioning it like in the picture. Is the aside good choice or how can this be solved in other way? Here is my html

```
<section id = "overview"></section>
<aside>
    <h1>Serverstatus:</h1>
    <div id ="benutzerContainer">
        <h2 class = "firstLine">Benutzer</h2>
        <p class = "firstLine">Administrator</p>
    </div>
    <div id = "zeitContainer">
        <h2 class = "secondLine">Systemstartzeit</h2>
        <p class = "secondLine">10:00</p>
    </div>
    <div id = "datumContainer">
        <h2 class = "thirdLine">Systemstartdatum</h2>
        <p class = "thirdLine">06.03.2017</p>
    </div>
    <div id ="loginContainer">
        <h2 class ="fourthLine">Fehlgeschlagene <br />
        Logins</h2>         
        <p class ="fourthLine">3</p>
    </div>
    <aside>
```

and css

```
section#overview{
width: 100%
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(206,206,206,0.3),      rgba(206,206,206,1)); 

}
aside {
float: right;
width: 25%;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(206,206,206,0.3), rgba(206,206,206,1));
}
```

I'm not able to make the height 100% while floating right. As soon as I put position: absolute it goes all the way to the left, even float is set to right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about what you want, but is this what you want?

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(206, 206, 206, 0.3), rgba(206, 206, 206, 1));
}

* {  box-sizing: border-box;  }

section#overview {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px #ccc solid; /* Switch if overview if taller */
  float: left;
}

aside {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px #ccc solid;
}
```

```html
<section id="overview">
  afwef foawjp foij oaijfw eoijfpa ojifojiaepo ijfapo jifpeo jiafwo f oijapojiefoajfweojifapofjiep ojioi jofiajpoj foajwejiawj ofji ofjawoj pofja oifjaeo jfaoji ojfaowj ofij ojfoawij pofijaw pofijawepoj 
</section>
<aside>
  <h1>Serverstatus:</h1>
  <div id="benutzerContainer">
    <h2 class="firstLine">Benutzer</h2>
    <p class="firstLine">Administrator</p>
  </div>
  <div id="zeitContainer">
    <h2 class="secondLine">Systemstartzeit</h2>
    <p class="secondLine">10:00</p>
  </div>
  <div id="datumContainer">
    <h2 class="thirdLine">Systemstartdatum</h2>
    <p class="thirdLine">06.03.2017</p>
  </div>
  <div id="loginContainer">
    <h2 class="fourthLine">Fehlgeschlagene <br />
        Logins</h2>
    <p class="fourthLine">3</p>
  </div>
  <aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `height: 100%;` to the `aside` element and it makes the elements height span the full height of the parent element. Try adding a wrapper around both elements to contain them both. Try the code below.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fob7bvzz/).

***HTML***

```html
<div class="wrap">

    <section id="overview"></section>

    <aside>

        <h1>Serverstatus:</h1>

        <div id ="benutzerContainer">
            <h2 class="firstLine">Benutzer</h2>
            <p class="firstLine">Administrator</p>
        </div>
        <div id="zeitContainer">
            <h2 class="secondLine">Systemstartzeit</h2>
            <p class="secondLine">10:00</p>
        </div>
        <div id="datumContainer">
            <h2 class="thirdLine">Systemstartdatum</h2>
            <p class="thirdLine">06.03.2017</p>
        </div>
        <div id="loginContainer">
            <h2 class ="fourthLine">Fehlgeschlagene <br />Logins</h2>
            <p class="fourthLine">3</p>
        </div>

     </aside>

</div>
```

***CSS***

```css
.wrap {
    height: 2000px;
}

section#overview{
    width: 100%
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(206,206,206,0.3),      rgba(206,206,206,1)); 
}
aside {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(206,206,206,0.3), rgba(206,206,206,1));
}
```